Is an ADC DNL > 1 also effectively a missing code?
I'm currently studying for an exam and have a question regarding the ADC DNL.
In the lecture, we've learned that a DNL=-1 implies a missing code.
I understand that part and can easily visualize it.
However, if we assume a fixed Full scale voltage, isn't a DNL=+1 also essentially a missing code?
To visualize what I mean, I added (my understanding of) the transfer function of a 2-bit ADC. 
The ideal step sizes of 1 LSB are drawn in black (with the transfer curve in green) and the erroneous behavior is drawn in red.

So from my understanding, If given an analog input that reaches a maximum of V_FS, the code 11 would never occur.
Am I missing something?


Am I missing something?

You are missing that how you have drawn the red curve will also produce a significant INL. So, INL and a DNL together is what you have. If you had more bits in your ADC it would become clearer: -

The image above is from here. It shows areas where you have INL and areas where you have DNL. Hopefully you can now see that your red characteristic contains a significant DNL but, it also contains a significant INL. Sometimes they can be tricky to separate.
You can only reasonable see true DNL once INL is corrected for. And, you can't realistically determine INL until zero and gain errors have been removed. Hence DNL on its own can be really tricky to visualize.
